# Flow of quadratic vector field.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, quadratic-forms, vector-fields

I need to find the flow of the following vector field in $\mathbb{R}^n$ : $ \mathbf{y} \mapsto  \mathbf{y}\cdot\mathbf{n}\mathrm{A}\cdot \mathbf{y}$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is a given vector and $\mathrm{A}$ is a given $n\times n$ invertible matrix.

What I've found so far :

- If the dimension $n=1$, then $f_t(x) = x / (1-t*a*x)$ satisfies $\frac{d}{d t} f_t(x) = a*f_t(x)^2$ and $f_0(x)=x$, which answers the question.
- In arbitrary dimension $n$, this solution extends to  $f_t(\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{x} / (1-t*\mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{x})$, which is the flow of $\mathbf{y} \mapsto \mathbf{n}\cdot\mathbf{y} \mathbf{y}$, which answers the question for the identity matrix.

However, I couldn't further generalize this solution to an arbitrary invertible matrix $\mathrm{A}$.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you mean $ \mathbf{x} \mapsto  \mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{n}\mathrm{A}\cdot \mathbf{x}$? Is "$\cdot$" the scalar product? Is $\mathbf{n}\mathrm{A}$ a matrix product and thus a vector of $\mathbb R^n$? If so, what is the scalar product of three vectors?

Comment: @PaulFrost The only logical interpretation seems to be that the vector field is $x \mapsto \langle x,n \rangle \cdot (Ax)$ (I avoid bold for convenience)

Comment: Thanks @peek-a-boo ,this is exactly what I meant. Edit : corrected mistyped equation

Comment: It might be an inconvenience to type, but for this question atleast, please put brackets $()$ appropriately around vectors you're dotting, OR use $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ for the inner (dot) product of two vectors in $\Bbb{R}^n$, and use $\cdot$ for scalar multiplication. Currently it's a little difficult to parse which meaning is intended.